# Is it possible to scrape HTML hyperlink text, rather than just the URL?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape some text from :https://twitchtracker.com/criticalrole/games, in order to show a streamers most streamed game for a twitch pay data analysis project.

I am trying to scrape "Dungeons & Dragons" from the first row in the table, but so far Ive only scraped the href.

**My Code:** `table = soup2.find(id='games').select('a', limit=1) print(table)`

**Output** `[<a href="/criticalrole/games/509577"> Dungeons &amp; Dragons </a>]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_text()`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#get-text):

```py
print(table[0].get_text())
```